# Change Color of Canvas Box after clicking inside of it

Tags: javascript, php, canvas

I am currently working on a reservation system. I want to change the color of a Canvas after clicking inside of the Canvas. Also, the color should be changed to the old color when it is clicked again etc.

code of my reservation.php:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
            <h3>Platz 1</h3>
            <canvas id="court1" class="canvas" width="300" height="450" onclick="leftClickOnCanvasCourt()"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <h3>Platz 2</h3>
            <canvas id="court2" class="canvas" width="300" height="450"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <h3>Platz 3</h3>
            <canvas id="court3" class="canvas" width="300" height="450"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Code of my js.js:

```
function leftClickOnCanvas(){
var ausgewaehlt = false;
var canvas = document.getElementById('court1');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

if(ausgewaehlt = false){
    context.fillStyle = rgb(180, 128, 128);
    context.fill();
    ausgewaehlt = true;
} else if (ausgewaehlt = true){
    context.fillStyle = rgb(240, 128, 128);
    context.fill();
    ausgewaehlt = false;
}
```

}

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should get familiar with your [console.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console) It will tell you what your errors are.

- You need to have your correct function name in the HTML.
- Your RGB strings need to be quoted.
- You need to use comparison operators (`===`) instead of assignment operators (`=`).
- You need to use [`fillRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fillRect) instead of `fill()`.
- You need to move `ausgewaehlt` outside of the function, or else it is reset to `false` every time the function is run.

```js
var ausgewaehlt = false;

function leftClickOnCanvas() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('court1');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  if (ausgewaehlt === false) {
    context.fillStyle = 'rgb(180, 128, 128)';
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ausgewaehlt = true;
  } else if (ausgewaehlt === true) {
    context.fillStyle = 'rgb(240, 128, 128)';
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ausgewaehlt = false;
  }

}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4">
    <h3>Platz 1</h3>
    <canvas id="court1" class="canvas" width="300" height="450" onclick="leftClickOnCanvas()"></canvas>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <h3>Platz 2</h3>
    <canvas id="court2" class="canvas" width="300" height="450"></canvas>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <h3>Platz 3</h3>
    <canvas id="court3" class="canvas" width="300" height="450"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way how i can retrieve the value of ausgewaehlt when i want to reservate the choosen tennis courts?

Comment: yeah, you can use that variable anywhere you want it it's in the global scope.

Comment: I mean if i want to get all courts which have ausgewaehlt === true how do i do that?

Comment: You'll have to make a different variable for each court, or else assign it to the canvas itself. Please don't ask new questions in the comments. Post a new question.